# Show chronometer time at different color at different time interval

Tags: android, chronometer

In my android Apps I have used Chronometer,it works good.Now I want to view chronometer time in different color ie when chronometer is started it glow BLACK color and after 30 minutes it glow RED. How It is Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Chronometer is just a view which can be set to any color at any point of time.

```
chronometer.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Refer [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html)

For different time interval you need to implement a `OnChronometerTickListener` on your chronometer.
Here is an example:

```
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {
@Override
public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
      long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                        - chronometer.getBase();
}
});
```

Comment: when we use this above it's change the background color but where to define time interval. Thanks.